# Rails Cucumber scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am still relatively new to rails. Currently stuck at the step:

```
And I should see "THX-1138"
```

The previous amazingly passed. However I am stuck at the last step of the happy path. Below is a description of my error:

```
Then I should be on the Similar Movies page for "Star Wars" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
And I should see "THX-1138" # features/Search_movie_by_director.feature:25

Ambiguous match of "I should see "THX-1138"":
  features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:12:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'

  You can run again with --guess to make Cucumber be more smart about it
   (Cucumber::Ambiguous)
  features/Search_movie_by_director.feature:25:in `And I should see "THX-1138"'
```

In my **paths.rb** I've input:

```
When /the Similar Movies page for "(.*)"/   

   "/movies/the_same_director/xxx%20XXX"
```

In my movie steps (doubt this relevant) I've input:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |title|
   if page.respond_to? :should
      page.should have_content(title)
   else
      assert page.has_content?(title)
   end
end
```

And finally in my **movie_controller.rb**:

```
def the_same_director
   #left it empty for I think its relevant to the happy scenerio  
end
```

May someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ambiguous step names. The [cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber) treats the `Given`, `When`, `And`, and `Then` at the beginning of a step as a general placeholder.  So:

```
And I should see "   "
```

and

```
Then I should see "   "
```

are really the same step (`Cucumber` will see all of the files in the step_function folder regardless of which feature file is calling them)

If they are supposed to do exactly the same thing write the steps so they are identical in the feature file (switch them both to:

```
Then I should see "   "
```

then factor the step definition out (throw it in a **general_steps.rb** file).

If their behavior is different change the name of the step so they aren't ambiguous. for example:

```
Then I should see the movie title "  "
```

and

```
Then I should see the web site "  "
```

Otherwise, you can just call it with the `--guess` tag, when you launch cucumber use cucumber `--guess`.  This should work but you should still fix the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your timely feedback!